# How to graph sinusoidal functions

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

I understand how to graph sinusoidal functions, but how do you decide to choose an input? For $\cos(x)$, people choose $0, \frac{\pi}{2}, \pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}$, etc. but for $\cos(4x)$, choosing those same inputs would give the outputs: $1, 1, 1, 1$, etc. to get the outputs $0$ and $-1$, you need other inputs. How do I decide/find those inputs?

Comment: The period of $f(x) = \cos(4x)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Since $\cos(4 \cdot 0) = \cos(0) = 1$ is a maximum point, we can divide $\frac{\pi}{2}$ into four equal intervals, the corresponding points are $x = 0, \frac{\pi}{8}, \frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{8}$.  The next period then begins at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What do you mean by dividing pi/2 into equal intervals/corresponding points? How did you find them?

Comment: I am dividing the period into fourths, where the endpoints of the quarter periods are the points at which the function has a maximum, a minimum, or a zero.

Comment: How are those quarter periods? They don’t add up to pi/2. Sorry is I’m missing something obvious. I just want to make sure I understand this.

Comment: You are confusing the endpoints of the quarter periods with the quarter periods, which are the differences between successive endpoints.   For $f(x) = \cos(4x)$, the period is $\pi/2$ and $$\frac{\pi}{8} - 0 = \frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{3\pi}{8} - \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{3\pi}{8} = \frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

A possible hint may be: The numbers as $$x=k\pi/8, k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ would get you out of problems.

Comment: Stupid question, but you put a denominator of 8, I’m assuming that applies to my case of cos(4x), but what about any case such as cos(a * x)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph of the cosine function $f: \mathbb{R} \to [-1, 1]$ defined by $f(x) = \cos x$.

[image: cosine_graph]

Observe that at $0$, the function obtains its maximum value of $1$.  Its value falls to $0$ at $x = \pi/2$, continues to decrease to its minimum value of $-1$ at $x = \pi$, increases to $0$ at $x = 3\pi/2$, and continues to increase to its maximum value of $1$ at $x = 2\pi$.  The cycle then repeats itself.  In fact, the graph repeats itself every $2\pi$ radians.

If there exists a positive number $p$ such that $f(x) = f(x + p)$ for each $x$ in its domain, then we say that the function $f$ is [periodic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function). If there exists a smallest such $p$, the function is said to have *period* $p$.

The cosine function has period $2\pi$.

The function $g: \mathbb{R} \to [-1, 1]$ defined by $g(x) = \cos(4x)$ has frequency $4$, meaning that it complete four full cycles in one period of the cosine function 
$f: \mathbb{R} \to [-1, 1]$ defined by $f(x) = \cos x$.  Consequently, it has period 
$$T = \frac{2\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Notice that $g(4 \cdot 0) = g(0) = 1$.  Thus, the function $g$ also assumes it maximum value of $1$ at $x = 0$.  The value of the function $g(x) = \cos(4x)$ then decreases to $0$, which it reaches when
$$4x = \frac{\pi}{2} \implies x = \frac{\pi}{8}$$
It continues to decrease to its minimum value of $-1$, which it reaches when
$$4x = \pi \implies x = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
The function then increases to $0$, which it reaches when 
$$4x = \frac{3\pi}{2} \implies x = \frac{3\pi}{8}$$
The function continues to increase to its maximum value of $1$, which it reaches when
$$4x = 2\pi \implies x = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
Since $g$ has period $\pi/2$, the graph then repeats itself, as shown below.

[image: cosine_graph_with_frequency_four]

Notice that we have divided a period of the graph into four subintervals by determining the values at which the cosine function has its maximum and minimum values and $x$-intercepts, then used periodicity to draw the graph.

Alternatively, we could solve for the maxima, minima, and $x$-intercepts of $g(x) = \cos(4x)$, then draw a smooth curve through the points we obtain.

maxima: 
\begin{align*}
\cos(4x) & = 1\\
\cos(4x) & = \cos(2n\pi), n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
4x & = 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = \frac{n\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

minima: 
\begin{align*}
\cos(4x) & = -1\\
\cos(4x) & = \cos(\pi + 2n\pi), n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
4x & = \pi + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{n\pi}{2}, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

$x$-intercepts:
\begin{align*}
\cos(4x) & = 0\\
\cos(4x) & = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\right), n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
4x & = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}\\
x & = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{n\pi}{4}, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

You see that the inputs you gave as examples for $\cos x$ showed what might be considered as "interesting" values such as the maximum and minimum points as well as the roots (where the graph crosses the $x$ axis). Well when you draw any graph try to choose those points. So for $\cos (4x)$ do the same.

To find where the graph crosses the $x-$axis set $y=0$ and solve for $x$.

To find the maxima/minima/inflexions differentiate and set equal to zero and solve for $x$.

Comment: But how do I know which values are “interesting”?

Comment: I'll add that into the answer as an edit.